# How to stat a child?

Tags: npc, iron-kingdoms

So the starting stats for a human are:

- Physique:5

  - Spd:6
  - Str:4
- Agility:3

  - Prw:4
  - Poi: 4
- Intelligence:3

  - Arc: *
  - Per: 3

These are however for an adult, and are fit for a player character to begin adventuring.

Ignoring Prw/Poi as these are only needed in combat and I have decided will be set to 1 what changes should I make to get a resonable stats for a child of the age 11/12?

Option 1) Half all of the other stats

Option 2) Reduce only some, and if so what ones and by how much?

Comment: "Child" is a term that covers a very wide range of ages. Is this a child who hasn't learned to walk yet? Is this a child that is approach the end of puberty?  (It's probably better to stat them for the role they play in the game than to attempt to be simulationist).

Comment: @Quentin: Never considered that implication. I'll include an age in the question viva edit. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

I'd reduce the sum of all experience-related stats by a certain amount:

- 1/10 or just "helpless" for ages 0-2
- 1/4 for ages 2-6
- 1/3 for ages 6-10
- 1/2 for ages 10-12
- 3/4 for ages 12 and up

I explicitly phrased "the sum of," for different kids have different abilities. Some climb better then adults, some are wiser, some have high EQ, some have high IQ, and some have weird combinations. All kids are however, still developing.

Comment: Is this answer based on things you have actually done, or just suggestions?

Comment: This is more based on my IRL experience as a dad, than anything else.